# Why isn't my request to the OMDb API working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, dom

This program will allow users to search for a movie by it's title, and using the OMDb API, will return (if found), the movie's title, release date and poster (if available). http://www.omdbapi.com/

I am having trouble with the request. No errors are being flagged in the console and the query string that I'm passing, if copy and pasted into another page in the browser, shows that it's getting the data.

I'm not getting any result though. In the chrome dev tools, under networks, it's saying that the response is being sent to my own home directory: `Request URL:file:///Users/mattcleary/Documents/Treehouse/movie_search/index.html?search=spiderman`.

But if that's the case, how is it putting together the right url for the API?

In the console, it's saying it's `jquery-3.1.0.js:9392 XHR finished loading: GET "http://www.omdbapi.com/?&s=inception&r=json"`, which is surely right?

Here is my code:

```
// BUILD A MOVIE SEARCH APP WITH THE OMDB API

// Request data from the OMDb API to display movie information
$('form').submit(function(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    var searchTerm = $('#search');
    var submitButton = $('#submit');

    var omdbAPI = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?';
    var title = searchTerm.val();
    var movieOptions = {
        s: title,
        r: "json"   
    };

    // Display search results on the page
    function displayMovies(data){
        var movieHTML = '';

        // If a result comes back
        if(data.response === true) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, movie) { 

                movieHTML += '<li><div class="poster-wrap">';

                // Show placeholder for poster if not available
                if(movie.Poster != "N/A"){
                    movieHTML += '<img class="movie-poster" src="' + movie.Poster + '"></div>';
                } else {
                    movieHTML += '<i class="material-icons poster-placeholder">crop_original</i>';
                }
                movieHTML += '<span class="movie-title">' + movie.Title + '</span><span class="movie-year">' + movie.Year + '</span></li>';
            });

        // If there aren't any results  
        } else if (data.Response == "False" || typeof data.Response == "undefined") {
            movieHTML += "<li class='no-movies'> <i class='material-icons icon-help'>help_outline</i>No movies found that match: " + title + "</li>";
        }

        // The data should load inside the #movies <ul>
        $('#movies').html(movieHTML);

    }

    $.getJSON(omdbAPI, movieOptions, displayMovies);
});
```

Any idea what's happening here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I removed `r: "json"` from the `var movieOptions` and that generated the xhr. I'm not sure why this is happening but I think it may be that the results are json format by default. I'm currently working on the same project and had the same problem when I started it. Hope this helped!